# How to translate(or shift) images in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to make my input image (tensor) of my model to shift up/down or right/left and then pad.

For example, if the original image is 3x3 like below,

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then, if I shift to left,

```
2 3 0
5 6 0
8 9 0
```

I found that there is an image rotate function in Tensorflow but I couldn't find translate or shift.
Please let me know if there is a built-in function,
or suggest the way to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can combine `tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box` and `tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box` to achieve this. 
Here's the API: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Cropping

Comment: link is no more valid

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a function to do this based on tf.contrib.image.transform:
https://gist.github.com/astromme/8116a154be8dae5528f33669e490c19a

```
## Tensorflow image translation op
# images:        A tensor of shape (num_images, num_rows, num_columns, num_channels) (NHWC),
#                (num_rows, num_columns, num_channels) (HWC), or (num_rows, num_columns) (HW).
# tx:            The translation in the x direction.
# ty:            The translation in the y direction.
# interpolation: If x or y are not integers, interpolation comes into play. Options are 'NEAREST' or 'BILINEAR'
def tf_image_translate(images, tx, ty, interpolation='NEAREST'):
    # got these parameters from solving the equations for pixel translations
    # on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/transform
    transforms = [1, 0, -tx, 0, 1, -ty, 0, 0]
    return tf.contrib.image.transform(images, transforms, interpolation)
```

Use it like this:

```
translation_op = tf_image_translate(images, tx=-5, ty=10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    translated_images = sess.run(translation_op)
```

Comment: hi, could you explain why does transform has 8 axis like "[1, 0, -tx, 0, 1, -ty, 0, 0]" ? Isn't 2 or 4 axis enough for the translation?

Comment: @zheyuanWang tf.contrib.image.transform is a generic transform function and can do lots of things beyond just translation. You'll notice most of the parameters are fixed and only tx and ty are variable. In any case, this is an old comment and tf.contrib.image.translate looks like a better option now!

Comment: What is the sense of lossy interpolation for the translation

Answer (score 5):

There is now a function for this (at least, as of TF v1.6): 
[tf.contrib.image.translate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/translate)